# MonogDB: How to get all the documents with specific value in a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of 10 unique Object IDs named **Arr**
I have 10,000 documents in a collection named **xyz**.

How can I find documents using Object IDs in the array **Arr** from the collection **xyz** with only one request?

There are $all and $in operators but are used to query fields with an array.

Or do I need to make requests equal to the length of **Arr** and get individual document using findOne?

**EDIT:**
I'm expecting something like this:

db.getCollection("xyz").find({"_id" : [array containing 10 unique IDs]})

....for which the result callback will contain an array of all the matched IDs of query array.

Comment: I believe you can directly query for content of a simple array: db.getCollection("xyz").find({"Arr" : "someId"})

Comment: Check out the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

You should use the following query:

```
db.getCollection("xyz").find({"Arr" : { $in: [123, 456, 789 ] }});
```

Comment: Tried and worked. Thanks. Bit confused with $in before.